# How to convert image file into binary in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing this code inside controller

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
```

I am getting this error

> The best overloaded method match or System.IO.FileStream.FileStream
>   has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Could you show your whole controller action that reads file?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public byte[] NewReport(string filename)
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            

        }

Comment: I even tried by converting type of argument from string to HttpPostedFileBase but again the same error. It also says that teh incoming file is empty...

Comment: Are you sure that it's real action? it contains two errors: fileName and filename - different variables and it doesn't return any value. If you want to return report by name - I think you should use HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/folderwithfiles" + filename). HttpPostedFileBase - for posting the file on the server, but what would be the purpose of action? just return posted file?

Comment: No I want to save it in sql server database

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but I would use just shortcut for this type of task:

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

EDIT:
If you want to post file in action and then save it in db - easiest way to do it is post it with form:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("NewReport")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then your action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewReport(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
    //here the code that saves image to db and returns action result
}
```

Note that max length of posted file in asp.net is 4Mb, but you easily can extend to size suitable for you in web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!--here I extend max length to 200Mb-->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I even tried this one but its still giving error on "File" . It says System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File is a method which is not valid in the given context. Morever filename that is coming from arguments is also null.

Comment: I updated my answer with code snippet that posts file into the server and gets bytes from poseted file. Hope it will help.